# using groovy to get the cvs's informations from xml folder

Tags: xml, groovy

I have a **folder** that have a lot of file `.xml` which are formatted like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<psf version="2.0">
    <provider>
        <project reference="1.0,:pserver:cvs.server:/cvs/repo1,project_1,project_1,branche_1"/>
        <project reference="1.0,:pserver:cvs.server:/cvs/repo1,project_1,project_1,branche_2"/>
        <project reference="1.0,:pserver:cvs.server:/cvs/repo2,project_1,project_1,branche_1"/>
        <project reference="1.0,:pserver:cvs.server:/cvs/repo3,project_1,project_1,branche_1"/>
  ...snip...
    </provider>
</psf>
```

I wrote a groovy scrip to get all the cvs informations so that I can `co` every project that exists in that files.

```
import groovy.io.FileType
def list = []
def CVSROOT= []
def PRO=[]
def BRA=[]
new File ('xml/folder').eachFile(FileType.FILES) { file ->
    def psf = new XmlParser().parse(file)
    psf.provider[0].project.each
    {
        list << it.'@reference'.split(/(^1.0|,)/)
    }
```

The problems is: **That is have alot of duplicate cvs informations in per file.(the same CVSROOTs, PROJECTS, BRANCHES).**

Any solutions for me. Thanks in advance! I am a newbie in groovy

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this inline:

```
def projects = new File('/xml/folder').listFiles()
    .findAll { it.file && it.name.endsWith('.xml') }
    .collectMany { file ->
        new XmlParser().parse(file)
                       .provider
                       .project.@reference*.split(/(^1.0|,)/)*.findAll()
                       .collect {
            [ url:it[0], name:it[1], branches:it[2..-1] ]
        }
    }
```

To give you back a list of maps like so:

```
[[url::pserver:cvs.server:/cvs/repo1, name:project_1, branches:[project_1, branche_1]],
 [url::pserver:cvs.server:/cvs/repo1, name:project_1, branches:[project_1, branche_2]],
 [url::pserver:cvs.server:/cvs/repo2, name:project_1, branches:[project_1, branche_1]],
 [url::pserver:cvs.server:/cvs/repo3, name:project_1, branches:[project_1, branche_1]]]
```

(not sure how you want to split the `reference` attribute, so I took a guess -- it's a long time since I used CVS, and I can't remember the format) ;-)